# Can't pass float value to GLSL?

Tags: linux, opengl, glsl

I try to send values to the GLSL, int is just all right, but float comes out strange.

Ubuntu 10.04LTS

Graphics card: G105M

Here is my vertex shader:

```
#version 110

attribute vec4 a_vertex;
attribute vec3 a_texCoord;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;

uniform float u_time;

void main()
{
    gl_Position=vec4(a_vertex.x+u_time,a_vertex.y,a_vertex.z,1);
    v_texCoord=a_texCoord.xy;
}
```

Here is my c code:

```
GLint timeLoc=glGetUniformLocation(splash_screen.proHandle,"u_time");
glUniform1f(timeLoc,1.0);
```

Here is the strange thing: if I change the u_time to int type, it works all right. But if I go with a float it is very strange.

if I use int,the vertex x will +1,but if i use float the vertex x not change.

I think i found it.

I port my program to Android,it work well.

It's my computer's problem(90% is the graphic card driver)

Comment: Define "strange" -- runtime error? Incorrect visual?

Comment: if I use int,the vertex x will +1,but if i use float the vertex x not change.(PS:I have edit the code above)

Comment: Ok. If you've found the answer to your question, please post it as an answer, then mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'am a newer in stackoverflow.Thanks for you suggestion,it help me lot.

Comment: No problem. Now that you've posted an answer to your own question, you should "accept" the answer (click the check next to your answer). This tells StackOverflow you no longer need an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finall found it.

I port my program to android,it work well

It's my computer's problem(90% is the graphic card driver)